# The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints

I get an the error:

> The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint

for each of my constraints when I run the code below, which is located in a `UIView` class:

```
func addIcon(iconImage: UIImage) {
    // Creating imageView
    var icon = UIImageView()
    icon.image = iconImage
    icon.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit

    // Adding to self
    self.addSubview(icon)

    // Setting constraints
    setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

    var leading = NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: icon,
        attribute: .Leading,
        relatedBy: .Equal,
        toItem: self,
        attribute: .Leading,
        multiplier: 1,
        constant: 8)
    icon.addConstraint(leading)

    var centerY = NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: icon,
        attribute: .CenterY,
        relatedBy: .Equal,
        toItem: self,
        attribute: .CenterY,
        multiplier: 1,
        constant: 0)
    icon.addConstraint(centerY)

    var top = NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: icon,
        attribute: .Top,
        relatedBy: .GreaterThanOrEqual,
        toItem: self,
        attribute: .Top,
        multiplier: 1,
        constant: 8)
    icon.addConstraint(top)

    var bottom = NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: icon,
        attribute: .Bottom,
        relatedBy: .GreaterThanOrEqual,
        toItem: self,
        attribute: .Bottom,
        multiplier: 1,
        constant: 8)
    icon.addConstraint(bottom)

    var width = NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: icon,
        attribute: .Width,
        relatedBy: .Equal,
        toItem: nil,
        attribute: .NotAnAttribute,
        multiplier: 1,
        constant: 20)
    icon.addConstraint(width)
}
```

Does anybody have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Define the constraints either in constructor or override layoutsubviews. Also check if you are adding the constraints to parent.

Comment: setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints must be called on the crated view. Also, you must add your constraints to the superview instead of `icon`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to roronoa zorro and pe60t0, I figured out that instead of just `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)` I should do this on the relevant view, so: `icon.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)`. 
Also the constraints should be added when the view is created, so I call override `layoutSubviews()` and add them there.
Finally I should add the constraints to the superview, and not the view I'm "making the constraints for". So instead of `icon.addConstraint(top)` I should write: `self.addConstraint(top)`.